# How do I exclude an inherited field in a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following form and inherited form:

```
class UsuarioAdminForm(ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Nombre', help_text = 'Nombre del usuario', required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Apellidos', help_text = 'Apellidos del usuario', required=True)
    dni = ESIdentityCardNumberField(help_text = 'DNI del usuario', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'size': 9}))
    username = forms.CharField(label='Login', help_text = 'Requerido. 30 caracteres o menos. Letras, números y @/./+/-/_', widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'size': 15}))
    #password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'size': 12}), label='Contraseña', help_text = 'Contraseña del usuario')
    email = forms.EmailField(help_text = 'Correo electrónico del usuario', required=True)
    movil = ESPhoneNumberField(help_text = 'Movil principal del usuario', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'size': 9 }))
    is_staff = forms.BooleanField(label = "Administrador", help_text = 'Marque la casilla si desea crear un administrador')
    tipo_u = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Tipo de usuario', choices = TipoUsuarios)
    def clean(self):
        try:
            cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
            movil = self.cleaned_data['movil']
            dni = self.cleaned_data['dni']
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Todos los campos del Formulario son Obligatorios.')

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        exclude = ('is_active','date_joined', 'last_login', 'user_permissions', 'tipo', 'groups', 'is_superuser', )


class UsuarioForm(UsuarioAdminForm):

    is_staff = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_staff = None
        super(UsuarioForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        exclude = ('is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined', 'last_login', 'user_permissions', 'tipo', 'groups', 'is_superuser', 'password', )
```

But when I create a UsuarioForm object, why does it show the is_staff field?

Update:

If i put `self.fields['is_staff'] = None` i obtain the next error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at
>   /sms/usuarios/add/user/
>
> Caught AttributeError while rendering:
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'label'

Comment: it is easier to add then remove, create UsuarioForm without "is_staff" field and UsuarioAdminForm wil have only one - actual "is_staff=.." (this is simplest and will always work). to remove a class attribute you can use del(self.is_staff) (in __init__) but this may have additional consequences as there are MetaClasses involved - so try not to use it. :)

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you could change the order of this lines:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UsuarioForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
    self.is_staff = None
```

You could also do:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UsuarioForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields.pop('is_staff')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but starting in Django 1.7.x you can just do the following:

```
class UsuarioForm(UsuarioAdminForm):

    is_staff = None

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        exclude = ('is_active', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'user_permissions', 'tipo', 'groups', 'is_superuser', 'password')
```

The `exclude` portion of `Meta` is only for excluding `ModelForm` elements, but any form element can be excluded by setting it to `None` in the declarations.

From the [Django docs on subclassing forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#subclassing-forms):

> It’s possible to declaratively remove a Field inherited from a parent
>   class by setting the name of the field to None on the subclass. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> >>> from django import forms
>
> >>> class ParentForm(forms.Form):
> ...     name = forms.CharField()
> ...     age = forms.IntegerField()
>
> >>> class ChildForm(ParentForm):
> ...     name = None
>
> >>> ChildForm().fields.keys()
> ... ['age']
> ```

**EDIT**:

I think the above works in the example given, but it doesn't seem to work for fields that are created due to the `Meta` on the `ModelForm`.  I think in those cases you need to inherit from the parent's `Meta` and change the fields given.

Answer (score -1):

Django form instances store the fields in the 'fields' attribute on the form itself, so in your **init**, after calling super, you need something like the following:

```
self.fields['is_staff'] = None
```

That should solve your problems; setting self.is_staff is just an unrelated variable (the is_staff you set on the class is a class variable not an instance variable).

Comment: If i put self.fields['is_staff'] = None  i obtain the next error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /sms/usuarios/add/user/

Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'

Comment: You need to add in logic when you are displaying it to only show it if the object has it. If this is only important in the admin section then you could actually just use the 'exclude' setting on the ModelAdmin class. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude

Comment: setting field to None will make all the things worst, if you need - remove this from the list (using `del`) but *do nott set it to None* as it is expected to be an instance of BaseField and is not will crash badly